# dropdown not set properlly on navbar for user name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

Signout dropdown not having proper position .
its changes as name of user increasing.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" >
    <li class="nav-item active pl-5">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home
        <span class="sr-only">(current)
        </span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item active pl-5">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/Dashboard">Dashboard
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item active pl-5">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/Visitor/VisitorAnalysis">Visitors Analysis
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item dropdown pl-5">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Users
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Users">Users List
            </a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Users/Create">User Create
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 pl-5">
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <ul style=" list-style-type: none;">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" style="text-decoration:none">
                    <span class="float-right">

                        @User.FindFirst("name").Value
                        <img src="~/images/Laura_Bush_portrait.jpg" class=" rounded-circle ml-3" style="width:26px;height:26px;" />

                    </span>

                    <b class="caret">
                    </b>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="margin-top: 33%;min-width:7rem; display: none;">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/AzureAD/Account/SignOut" style="margin-left:4%;">Sign out
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    }

    else
    {
        <div class='quick-area'>
            <div class='pull-right'>
                <ul style=" list-style-type: none;">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a asp-area="AzureAD" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn" style="color:rgb(22,53,71)">Sign in
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</form>
```

Signout dropdown not having proper position .
its changes as name of user increasing.
Signout dropdown not having proper position .
its changes as name of user increasing.
As name of user name length increases , its signout dropdown goes down, how to solve it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS wrap word property to set the user name length when you show it

[https://www.techonthenet.com/css/properties/word_wrap.php#:~:text=Description,to%20fit%20within%20its%20container](https://www.techonthenet.com/css/properties/word_wrap.php#:%7E:text=Description,to%20fit%20within%20its%20container).

Comment: add <span style='word-wrap: normal; width: 25px;' >   user name </span> and adjust the width as per the size of box